# Add comments to the version history

Tags: 2013, version-history

When you upload a new document you are able to add comments which are visible in the version history. If edit an exisiting document and save it you do have the option to add comments??  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have the option to add comments if check in/check out is required on the library. This will then allow you add comments on check in via the UI or the office application.

Comment: This option is under "Versioning settings"

Comment: Is there any option to add version Comments without enabling check-in/check-out?